# How can I make a custom stream collector in java 8 use single thread to do the processing?

Tags: parallel-processing, java-8, java-stream, collectors

Generally, I am writing a custom stream collector, which is combined with a supplier, an accumulator, and an combiner for my knowledge. In my custome collector, I realize the accumulator is not thread-safe, so I set the combiner be `null` and the `Collector.Characteristics` be `IDENTITY_FINISH`. The codes can pass the compiling but there is runtime exception, as combiner should not be null, which is already indicated by the NotNull annotation.

My question is if I supply a combiner in my collector with `Collector.Characteristics` being `IDENTITY_FINISH`, will the accumulator run in parallel (or concurrently) or just in a single thread without race problem?

Comment: If you don't want your collector to be used in parallel, you can throw an exception when implementing the combiner, but as long as you don't report the `CONCURRENT` characteristic, the accumulator does not need to be thread-safe AFAIK.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use `null` for any function which used in collector (including supplier, accumulator, combiner and finisher). The common solution when you cannot provide a proper combiner is to pass a throwing lambda:

```
(a, b) -> {throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Combining is not supported");}
```

After that you can use your `Collector`. Though this is still bad practice as `Collector` interface does not permit not implementing the combiner.

Please note that unless you're specifying explicitly `CONCURRENT` characteristic, you don't need to worry about thread-safety. If your collector is not concurrent, parallel stream will call supplier in separate threads, then use accumulator there independently and finally call the combiner only after all the accumulation is finished. It's the whole point of collectors: it's guaranteed that for non-concurrent collector you don't need the thread-safety, no concurrent operations with the same container will be performed. That's why supplier is necessary: it could be called several times to create several independent containers for each thread.

Finally note that if you don't have a finisher, you don't need to specify explicitly `IDENTITY_FINISH`. Just use

```
Collector<?,?,?> myCollector = Collector.of(mySupplier, myAccumulator, myCombiner);
```

The `IDENTITY_FINISH` characteristic will be added automatically.